# Get Procentual Value in PHP

Tags: php

Well I was working on this now too long, and Google did not help either:

I have the value 100.50
How can I do 100.50 - 10.1% in PHP? So that output would be 90.45

Somehow using my PHP methods I get output like 90.12124502540540405

Comment: Post your code. Your maths doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a typo in your expected result, rounded to 2 decimal places:

```
echo round(100.5 * ((100 - 10.1) / 100), 2); //90.35
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$x = 100.5;
$p = 10.1;
$result = $x*(1-$p/100);
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
90.3495
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18d53a0bc022c9dff30858001ff2c442885ad2ae

Answer (score 0):

PHP just not support the notation `$val-10%`,

However, percentage are just a fraction multiplied by 100.

```
$val=100.50;
$percent=10.1;
$result=$val*(1-$percent/100);
```